# Chrome adds a leading space on paragraphs

Tags: css, google-chrome, text-indent

I'm using Chrome 41 on OS X. A live example will illustrate much more easily my issue: http://mathieumarques.herokuapp.com/.

If you scroll down to the *Experiences* section, you can see a leading space in front of each paragraph, even if I force `text-indent: 0;`. I can however add a negative value for the `text-indent` property.

I don't have this issue on Firefox.

Comment: There is a new-line character(s) before the text, within the `<p>`, remove it

Comment: And the leading `whitespace`.

Comment: @Alex Feel free to add an actual answer. The content of each panel is dynamic and indeed added a new line after the opening paragraph bracket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tabs/spaces/character in the markup are causing it.

Removing them fixes the issue.

Old:

```
<div class="lead timeline-body ng-scope" ng-transclude="" ng-bind-html="item.description"><p>
Web development with Django and jQuery.
Porting of a desktop C++ application to the
Web. Realization of a single page
application, with vectorial drawing on
mouse events.
</p>
```

New:

```
<div class="lead timeline-body ng-scope" ng-transclude="" ng-bind-html="item.description"><p>Web development with Django and jQuery. Porting of a desktop C++ application to the Web. Realization of a single page application, with vectorial drawing on mouse events.</p>
```

Comment: As said in my comment above, I `POST` the content through a form and the content is then inserted but with a new line character after `<p>`. So to make it slightly more readable I can start putting new line characters after the first word (*web* here).